# How to configure Yii2 i18n for storing messages in database instead of files?

Tags: php, internationalization, yii2

I find Yii2 documentation seriously lacking in documentation about i18n, particularly about using database instead of files for the translation messages.

I see [documentation](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager) (EDIT: sorry, [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#message-translation) was the link I meant) mentions the DbMessageSource class and somewhere else I found that the db tables should be named `source_message` and `message` but nowhere does it tell me the schema for those tables! And the `yii message/extract` command doesn't seem to auto-create the tables either.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your documentation link is about a yii2 extension, you should read instead :

- [Internationalization - Message Translation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#message-translation)
- [yii\i18n\DbMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html)

> If you don't want to use migration and need SQL instead, files for all databases are in migrations directory.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework/i18n/migrations

For example, the schema for MySQL is :

```
CREATE TABLE `source_message`
(
   `id`          integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   `category`    varchar(255),
   `message`     text
);

CREATE TABLE `message`
(
   `id`          integer NOT NULL,
   `language`    varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   `translation` text
);

ALTER TABLE `message` ADD CONSTRAINT `pk_message_id_language` PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `language`);
ALTER TABLE `message` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_message_source_message` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `source_message` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

> The `source_message` table stores the messages to be translated, and the `message` table stores the translated messages. The name of these two tables can be customized by setting `$sourceMessageTable` and `$messageTable`, respectively.

Comment: Saw the reference to the folder but without mentioning in which package the folder can be found it was pretty helpless since it wasn't in the installed package :) Thanks for the link. (Intended linking the documentation in the question, now fixed)

Comment: The configuration file for using DbMessageSource should be setup as follow : 
'i18n' => ['translations' => ['app*' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
        ]]], Where the category is app* and the tables use default names.